# jquery call user function from plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create a simple jquery plugin for my project

I want to call user function from plugin, how to do it

my code
When user passes below options i want to call ss function

```
{id:"today",value:"Today",func: "ss()"},
```

here is my plugin code

```
$('#drop1').append("<li id='"+options.items[i].id+"' onclick='"+options.items[i].func+"'>"+options.items[i].value+"</li>");
```

this is not calling user function, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj6he/2/)

Use event delegation when you add dynamic dom element .
Here i made simple sample for your related questions

```
var options={id:"today",value:"Today",func: ss}

     $('#drop1').append("<li id='"+options.id+"'>"+options.value+"</li>");
     $('#drop1').on("click","#"+options.id,options.func); // here you can bind the event 

function ss(){
    alert(1);
    }
```